# Xcode enable objc exceptions

Tags: ios, xcode

I find that if I set enable objc exceptions to No in Xcode, the size of executable file will be smaller. Who can explain it? I have create a demo with a function:

```
- (void)testExceptionsenter code here
{
    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    NSLog(@"%@", self.book);
}
```

and the size of .o file changes if I set enable objc exceptions to No.

Comment: the compiler generates the machine code for every possible code path.

Comment: Can you point in more detail? Even I do not use try-catch in class, the .o file after compiling becomes smaller.

Comment: no, thats why I left a comment instead an answer.